# Gutter overhang past end of drip edge

Tags: drainage, gutters

My gutter has a 4" overhang past the end of drip edge. Does this do anything or can I just not have it in my next gutter that I am working on?

It's a mod bit 10 degree roof that all drains into this gutter.

[image]

Comment: "Mod bit 10"? What's that?

Comment: **Mod**ified **bit**umen and speech to  text, probably. Or just shorthand and it's 10 degrees slope, in context.

Comment: @Ecnerwal that is correct

Answer (score 1):

This is fairly normal, though the exact overhang is a matter of installer preference. You want some extension because there can be a fairly high flow at the corner and wind can push it outward. I'd say 1-2" is fine in most cases, though it should be a bit more for long drops.